# How to choose FlexSpi channel in IAR

Tags: iar, imx7

I have two boards with MIMXRT1176 microcontroller. On one board the chip connected to an external flash with FlexSpi_1 (address 0x30000000), on other with FlexSpi_2 (address 0x60000000).

On the first board I choose a linker file in IAR

> define symbol m_interrupts_start       = 0x30002000;

> define symbol m_interrupts_end         = 0x300023FF;

> define symbol m_text_start             = 0x30002400;

> define symbol m_text_end               = 0x30FBFFFF;

> define exported symbol m_boot_hdr_conf_start = 0x30000400;

> define symbol m_boot_hdr_ivt_start           = 0x30001000;

> define symbol m_boot_hdr_boot_data_start     = 0x30001020;

> define symbol m_boot_hdr_dcd_data_start      = 0x30001030;

> define exported symbol core1_image_start     = 0x30FC0000;

> define exported symbol core1_image_end       = 0x30FFFFFF;

And it’s downloaded and runs OK.

For the second board I modify a linker file.

> define symbol m_interrupts_start      = 0x60002000;

> define symbol m_interrupts_end         = 0x600023FF;

> define symbol m_text_start             = 0x60002400;

> define symbol m_text_end               = 0x60FBFFFF;

> define exported symbol m_boot_hdr_conf_start = 0x60000400;

> define symbol m_boot_hdr_ivt_start           = 0x60001000;

> define symbol m_boot_hdr_boot_data_start     = 0x60001020;

> define symbol m_boot_hdr_dcd_data_start      = 0x60001030;

> define exported symbol core1_image_start     = 0x60FC0000;

> define exported symbol core1_image_end       = 0x60FFFFFF;

And I get an error – The flash loader program reported an error.

Obviously I miss some additional settings that have to be made to connect to FlexSpi_2. What is it?